# Position fixed cover text

Tags: html, css

I need the main content to stay at the right side of the sidebar.
Now you can notice that sidebar is covered by the body content because of fixed position.

Is there a solution fix avoid this issue without adding margin right for the main content?

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
}

.s {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class='s'>sidebar</div>
  <div class='m'>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `margin-right`?, Did you consider `position:sticky` instead, it might be more appropriate here.

Comment: Please see [ask] and revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position:sticky` instead.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.App {
  display: flex;
}

.s {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-self: flex-start;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class='s'>sidebar</div>
  <div class='m'>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the sidebar with an element with fixed width.

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
}

.s1 {
  width: 100px;
}

.s {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="s1">
    <div class='s'>sidebar</div>
  </div>
  <div class='m'>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add width to `app` and use `margin-left: auto;` on your content.

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}

.s {
  position: fixed;
}

.m {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class='s'>sidebar</div>
  <div class='m'>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
  </div>
</div>
```